# Oracle APEX Download - xls

Tags: oracle, download, oracle-apex, xls

I have installed the Sample Database Application on https://apex.oracle.com and have the ability to download an Interactive Report to xls.  I have installed the same sample application on a local installation of APEX 5.1 and enabled the xls as a download option for the same interactive report, but when selecting download from the report it is not showing as an option for downloading.

Is there something else that needs to be enabled/configured to allow this download option?  The documentation does not mention any additional configuration/steps that would be required from what I have found.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/bldapp_rpt_int.htm#HTMDB25361

Answer (score 0):

In interactive reports, especially version 4 and before, the report conditions hide the download buttons, due to reasons unknown. Can you check whether removing any conditions makes a difference ?

Comment: This should have be a comment.